# How to set time for cron job every day at 9 AM to 11 AM and 5 PM to 6PM

Tags: java, spring, cron, scheduled-tasks

I want to create a **Cron Job** that executes twice a day for 6 days. In the morning 9 to 11 and evening from 5 to 6 on Monday to Saturday

I have tried:

`@Scheduled(cron = "0/4 * 9-11 * * ?")`

But then it executes every 4 seconds between 9-11 **BUT** also after 11.

*What am I doing wrong?*

Comment: Hi @Sandip, What have you tried?

Comment: @Reg yes I tried like this  @Scheduled(cron = "0/4 * 9-11 * * ?") every 4 seconds between 9-11 but after 11 also job is running. It should be stop after 11 buts its still running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below cron expression triggers job every 4 seconds between 9AM-10:59AM and 5PM-5:59PM daily on Monday to Saturday.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0/4 * 9-10,17 * * MON-SAT")
```

Also refer http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/crontrigger.html

Comment: i think you did not understand my question, 9AM to 11AM , after 11Am to 4.59PM stop and again start at 5PM to 6PM only 3 hours it should be run other 22 hours it must be stop.

Comment: Edited the answer, please check. Giving 9-11, would satisfy 9 to 11:59, so we need to give 9-10:59.